# Mono Package for Wine is not installed

Tags: wine, mono

Wine is saying that Mono package is not installed, but I installed it with Terminal by:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

What should I do?

Comment: Wine needs the *Windows* build of Mono, which I think you can install using `winetricks`. I'm a bit hazy on the specifics -- maybe someone else can take this clue and flesh out a step-by-step answer.

Comment: yeah I need a step-by-step answer, thanks anyway

Comment: Try looking at the official docs ... [https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono](https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Do the following to install `wine-mono`:

1. Download [wine-mono.msi](https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/) from the official WineHQ site.
2. Type `wine64 uninstaller`.
3. Press install from the uninstaller GUI and select the downloaded .msi package.
4. Done!

Comment: "Press install from the uninstaller" how intuitive

Comment: With $USER, get "There is no Windows program configured to open this type of file". From $ROOT, it does see mono runtimes (I did reload because I didnt see a response). `wine KeePass.exe` still not working, even with sudo. And after trying the other answers. "Wine Mono is not installed"

Comment: @AlejandroRamallo very well in the Windows idiom ;)

Comment: I get the error "There is no Windows program configured to open this type of file"

Comment: Great answer, on headless machines like a CI, this doesn't work though. Using `wine msiexec /i wine-mono-X.Y.Z-x86.msi` however does. See [my answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1448770/734252) for more details.

Answer (score 43):

Installing .NET instead should work as well. For example by the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
winetricks dotnet45
```

Comment: I don't think it worked; nothing showed up in wine uninstaller after above.

Comment: didnt work for me either. didnt try rebooting.

Comment: I do not want to install wine-mono b/c of the wine howto here [keepass2_wine](https://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#wine)

But the howto does not work b/c of error:
`(base) leder@home-ryzen-desktop:~/Keepass2_portable$ wine KeePass.exe 
0009:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed
`

Comment: This works for me, thanks.

Comment: `Executing load_dotnet45 
------------------------------------------------------
warning: This package (dotnet45) is broken in wine-6.0.3. Broken since 5.18. See https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49897 for more info. Use --force to try anyway.
------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: It's not advised to install the .NET package. Instead really try to install Wine Mono instea!

Answer (score 6):

Other answers were not working for me on 18.04 LTS with `winehq-stable` package.

The workaround I found was to recreate wine32 and wine64 prefixes and install wine-mono on that with the automatic prompt.

```bsh
    # Create dir for 32 bit prefix
    mkdir ~/.wine32
    # destroy default configuration (64 bit prefix)
    rm -rf ~/.wine 

    # Initial setup (create prefixes)
    WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
    WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" WINEARCH=win64 wine64 wineboot

    # To install dotnet35 on 32-bit prefix
    WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 winetricks dotnet35
```

Answer (score 1):

[@PSN](https://askubuntu.com/a/992215/734252)'s answer worked for me, however I was in the situation of needing to do this from a script on a remote CI machine without a user interface available.

I suggest the following solution, which worked for me:

1. Download [wine-mono.msi](https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/) from the official WineHQ site (version 7.4.0 at the time of writing this).
2. Type `wine msiexec /i wine-mono-7.4.0-x86.msi`.
3. Done!

It's also possible to verify on the command line that installing Mono worked:

```
$ wine uninstaller --list
{47A1FA26-B71E-5325-8161-20CF885181FF}|||Wine Mono Runtime
{7426CCE2-5341-534D-BAB0-1DAEDCCE76CE}|||Wine Mono Windows Support
```

Side note: it's also possible to run the installer using `wine start wine-mono-7.4.0-x86.msi`. While there's no graphical installer coming up for the Mono MSI on a local machine, it does not work like this on a headless machine. Fortunately `wine msiexec /i wine-mono-7.4.0-x86.msi` seems to work without a display though.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily download and configure with Synaptic Package Manager :

- open Synaptic and search for *msitools*
- mark for installation and click *apply*.

Comment: nope, `apt search mistools && sudo apt install !$` installed but still cant run KeePass

Answer (score 0):

To install the right Wine Mono, you can find supported version in `appwiz.cpl` file as per suggestion from [here](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/1236#issuecomment-1518353592).

```
$ locate appwiz.cpl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine-development/appwiz.cpl
$ grep -aho 'w.i.n.e.-.m.o.n.o.-.[^-]*-.[^.]*..m.s.i.' /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine*/appwiz.cpl | head -n1
wine-mono-5.1.1-x86.msi
```

Then download it from https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/.

```
$ wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/5.1.1/wine-mono-5.1.1-x86.msi
```

And run the installer:

```
$ wine start wine-mono-5.1.1-x86.msi
```

Or run `wine uninstaller` and select the installer file.

Check also the following helper script at [install-wine-addon.sh](https://gist.github.com/jflemer/a1125763ea3fdb1fde2ca296675c7039).