# 22.04 Could not load type of field 'x360ce.App.MainForm:detector'

Tags: wine, winetricks, xbox-360

After the installation of wine32, wine64 and wine-stable following the steps from [this website](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-wine-linux/) and also [winetricks](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106750/849328), [wine-mono](https://askubuntu.com/a/992215/849328) and wine-gecko; I tried to run typing `wine x360ce_x64.exe` I got the error, then I tried with another file typing `wine x360ce_x86.exe` and I got the same error, the ouput is:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'x360ce.App.MainForm:detector'
(0) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'x360ce.Engine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=
neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

0090:err:rpc:I_RpcReceive we got fault packet with status 0x1c010003
```

Could anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dotnet45 via [winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks):

```
WINEPREFIX=/path/to/your/.wine_prefix winetricks dotnet45
```