# Installed dotnet6 package with Jammy but the Windows application is still asking for Mono

Tags: wine, mono, dotnet

I am trying to run SDRPlay2RSS.exe with wine. This is a piece of software based on the .NET framework, belonging to radiotelescope software for the Radio Jove project. I first tried installing wine mono and several dotnet dll versions with winetricks without success.

Then I learned that Ubuntu 22.04.1 Jammy Jellyfish provides built-in support of dotnet. After upgrading the kernel and installing the complete dotnet6 package I tried again to run SDRPlay2RSS.exe with wine. The result is that there still seems to be a need of mono:

0024:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed

Shouldn't wine use dotnet instead of mono?

Regards

Sabine

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an answer to my own question:

The dotnet6 runtime package is what it says, a runtime environment to run .NET code. No wine needed. BUT: It does not work cross-platform. So a Windows application like SDRPlay2RSS.exe will not run even when called with dotnet.

So I started from the beginning with wine mono. How to install the .msi package needed is described here precisely:
https://askubuntu.com/a/992215/1648853

but apparently I chose the wrong version. The .msi version must fit to the wine version. After installing mono, you have to install missing fonts using winetricks. Select "allfonts".

That's all! SDRPlay2RSS runs.